# Async/await button click blocks UI

Tags: vb.net

I have simple async button and also an async/await function. When i click on my button my UI get freezes. Could anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

```
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    LabelCounter.Text = "Running"
    LabelCounter.Text = await ComputeText()
End Sub
```

and this function:

```
Private Async Function ComputeText() As Task(Of String)
    Dim result as string = Await Task.Run(Function()
                                              'Thread.Sleep(2000)
                                              Dim i as Integer = 0
                                              While i <> 100000
                                                  i += 1
                                                  'block as other staff can access it as well from outside
                                                  SyncLock thisLock                                                   
                                                      LabelCounter.Invoke(Sub()
                                                                              LabelCounter.Text = i 
                                                                          End Sub)
                                                  End SyncLock
                                              End While

                                              Return "Done"
                                          End Function)
    Return result
End Function
```

Comment: You are using `Invoke` and this is a synchronous call.

Comment: Well, calling `Invoke` a hundred thousand times is probably not going to be best for performance.

Comment: @Glorin ah ok so thats why its frezzes mu UI (didnt know Invoke is synchronous). But first of all i have to update this label - so i have to use Invoke( as i am on diffrent thread, then i also have to make SyncLock as i have other tasks outside which are also updating that label. So this has to be done this right am i right? Is there any other way to implement?

Answer (score 0):

> When i click on my button my UI get freezes

As others have noted, even though you're using `Async`/`Await` (which is correct), the problem is the `Invoke`.

`Invoke` will interrupt the UI thread and tell it to do something (in this case, update a label). The problem is that the background thread is interrupting the UI 100,000 times as fast as it can.

The second piece of the puzzle is that UI messages are *prioritized*. `WM_PAINT` (that is, "redraw parts of the screen that need to be changed) is at a lower priority than the "run this arbitrary code" message. So, the UI literally doesn't have time to refresh because the background `Invoke` requests take priority and they're coming in too fast.

I recommend using the standard `IProgress<T>` approach for reporting progress, rather than updating labels and using `Invoke` directly. This has the advantage of separating your UI display from your program logic (running in the background thread); also, it uses a framework-agnostic approach (`IProgress<T>`) rather than tying your logic to WinForms specifically (`Invoke`).

The only real solution is to throttle the background updates. You can do this in the background logic itself (i.e., only issue an update every 1000 cycles or so), but this is not ideal because 1) It's a UI concern being addressed in your business logic; and 2) It can change over time based on system usage, CPU power, etc.

So, I recommend having the background logic *always* send updates (using `IProgress<T>.Report`), and have the `IProgress<T>` *implementation* throttle them. This is most easily done via Rx. Lee Campbell has a [blog post on the subject](https://leecampbell.com/2016/10/03/iprogress-and-rx-without-subjects/) (which is the more proper solution), and I have a [down-and-dirty git-er-done approach in a gist](https://gist.github.com/StephenCleary/4248e50b4cb52b933c0d) (which has not yet been updated to be more proper, but it's easy to just set up a pre-throttled progress).

Comment: So, what explains why I'm able to run his code just fine?  Better graphics card maybe?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary it seems Invoke do bad job here if i remove it there is no problem so invoke... Stephen could you be so kind and show as an asnwer how to change that code to make it works? P.S Is there any equivalent for Invoke to be asynchronous instead of synchronous?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: See the gist I posted for a usage example. There is a `BeginInvoke` for WinForms, but it won't help because the underlying problem (100,000 updates pounding the UI thread) will still be there.

Comment: @rory.ap: The code will run fine, it'll just block the UI. If you're not seeing the UI blocked, I'd double-check the code.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary does it mean since it's in the task so not blocking UI hoever we use inside task Invoke (which is synchronous) and therefore at the time Invoke is called it tread like synchronous so at this time will block UI for moment so if we have n-times and done mostly every second GUI is block for every occurence of it right? But if it would be couple time with breaks betwwen probably i would not see/feel it. is this all correct thinking and therefore you advice to use IProgress to update every control on forms?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: `Invoke` runs code on the UI thread (I wouldn't call it "synchronous", but I believe you have the right idea). Yes, if there were delays between updates, it would work (the UI thread would not be kept too busy). I do recommend using `IProgress<T>` if you are updating from a background thread, for the reasons mentioned in my answer.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary I am confused a bit now. If you say Invoke action will be done on UI even if it does from task action that would block UI at the time it was called. So going this approach i could think that any control e.g Label accesing from Task will be fired on UI thread. So what if app would have 100 tasks and every one would update control and also user would do something with it at the same time. UI will be completly freezes, am i right? What is then for Tasks if they would block UI in this case? Don't see any benefit. I thought from tasks access to controls is done 'transparently'.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary that means that controls calls even from tasks are done synchronously so if there are many of them will occupied UI and this leds to freeze ...

Comment: The `Await` means that the UI thread is not blocked. `I thought from tasks access to controls is done 'transparently'` - no, not at all. Only code running on the UI thread can update the UI. In this case, any code in the `Task.Run` is on a background thread, even though it's in a task.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary If i would have couple tasks and every of them would try to access label text property at same time this means each of those calls would be done synchronusly (on main ui thread even if they from tasks) then it would led to application freeze. Correct?

Comment: @JimmyJimm: No; they would just go one at a time.

Comment: @Stephen Cleary but you said control access is done on UI thread - i am not talking about the task itself but more like just those lines in those tasks that accessing label's text - i am thinking that way that only at those lines code behaviour (only for that line) is chaning to synchronous as if they working on UI - they will be done like in queue - therefore freeze. That's how i understand that. or mayby is there any picture that would show it clearly (just cant understand that) if my assumptions are wrong.

Comment: @JimmyJimm: Yes, they'll go one after another, like in a queue.